# Self join only returning one record

Tags: mysql, join

Working on an inventory management system, and we have the following tables:

```
================================================
| orders | order_line_items  | product_options | 
|--------|-------------------|-----------------|
| id     | id                | id              |
| start  | order_id          | name            |
| end    | product_option_id |                 |
|        | quantity          |                 |
|        | price             |                 |
|        | event_start       |                 |
|        | event_end         |                 |
================================================
```

I'm trying to calculate inventory on a certain date, so I need to make a self join to compare the *quantity* on order_line_items to the SUM of the quantity of other records in order_line_items with the same product_option_id, and where the event start and end are within a range.

So, given a date 2016-01-20, I have:

```
SELECT order_line_items.id, order_line_items.product_option_id, order_line_items.order_id FROM order_line_items
WHERE order_line_items.event_end_date >= '2016-01-20 04:00:00'
AND order_line_items.event_start_date <= '2016-01-21 04:00:00'
AND order_line_items.product_option_id IS NOT NULL;
```

The above returns 127 rows

When I try to do a self join, like so:

```
SELECT 
order_line_items.id, 
order_line_items.product_option_id, 
order_line_items.order_id, 
order_line_items.quantity, 

other_line_items.other_product_option_id, 
other_line_items.other_order_id, 
other_line_items.other_quantity, 
other_line_items.total 

FROM order_line_items

JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        product_option_id AS other_product_option_id, 
        order_id AS other_order_id, 
        quantity AS other_quantity, 
        SUM(quantity) total
    FROM order_line_items
    WHERE order_line_items.event_end_date >= '2016-01-20 04:00:00'
    AND order_line_items.event_start_date <= '2016-01-21 04:00:00'
) other_line_items ON order_line_items.product_option_id = other_line_items.other_product_option_id

WHERE order_line_items.event_end_date >= '2016-01-20 04:00:00'
AND order_line_items.event_start_date <= '2016-01-21 04:00:00'
AND order_line_items.product_option_id IS NOT NULL;
```

It only returns 1 record.  As you can see here: (https://goo.gl/BhUYxK) there are plenty of records with the same product_option_id so this last query should be returning a lot of rows

Comment: A suggestion, you need rename the second table, because the system can confuse, and don't need the second where, because you have one in the sub query.

Comment: Thanks -- removing the second where got me more records, but now all of the records returned have the same product_option_id .. weird: https://goo.gl/itL5bF

Comment: ok, try this in `join` option, `order_id = other_order_id and production_order_id = other_production_order_id`

Comment: Hmm, but I need to join on the product_option_id, because I'm trying to get the total quantity of all other records that match the product_option_id in the query-- has nothing to do with order_ids -- so I have x amount ordered on one line for a Chair ProductOption -- I need to know, out of all the other records that fit the query, what is the total quantity of Chairs ordered

Answer (score 2):

The added `SUM(...)` turns the subquery into a single row.  Perhaps the subquery needed to have one of these:

```
GROUP BY (id)
GROUP BY (product_option_id)
GROUP BY (order_id)
```

(I don't know the schema or application well enough to say which makes sense.)

(Please use shorter, more distinctive, aliases; the SQL is very hard to read because of the length and similarity of `order_line_items` and `other_line_items`.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually want to get the following ? :

```
SELECT product_option_id, sum(quantity)
FROM order_line_items
WHERE event_end_date   >= '2016-01-20 04:00:00'
AND   event_start_date <= '2016-01-21 04:00:00'
GROUP BY 1
```

I can not tell why you need a self join here

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you want without a sample result, but this will give you the comparison of quantity of each order's product options to the total within the range:

```
SELECT oli.order_id, 
       oli.product_option_id,
       oli.quantity,
       po.total_quantity   
  FROM order_line_items oli
  JOIN (
    SELECT product_option_id,
           SUM(quantity) total_quantity
      FROM order_line_items
     WHERE event_end   >= '2016-01-20 04:00:00'
       AND event_start <= '2016-01-21 04:00:00'
  GROUP BY product_option_id
       ) po
    ON po.product_option_id = oli.product_option_id
 WHERE oli.event_end   >= '2016-01-20 04:00:00'
   AND oli.event_start <= '2016-01-21 04:00:00'
```

If you can have multiple rows of the same product_option in an order you may need to tweak this as so:

```
  SELECT oli.order_id, 
         oli.product_option_id,
         SUM(oli.quantity) order_quantity,
         po.total_quantity   
    FROM order_line_items oli
    JOIN (
      SELECT product_option_id,
             SUM(quantity) total_quantity
        FROM order_line_items
       WHERE event_end   >= '2016-01-20 04:00:00'
         AND event_start <= '2016-01-21 04:00:00'
    GROUP BY product_option_id
         ) po
      ON po.product_option_id = oli.product_option_id
   WHERE oli.event_end   >= '2016-01-20 04:00:00'
     AND oli.event_start <= '2016-01-21 04:00:00'
GROUP BY oli.order_id, 
         oli.product_option_id
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you actually should be left joining the `orders` and `product_options` to the `order_line_items` table.

Your query should look something like this, for the quantity of items on orders between certain dates.

```
SELECT product_options.id, production_options.name, SUM(order_line_items.quantity)
FROM order_line_items
LEFT JOIN product_options ON production_options.id=order_line_items.product_option_id
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id=order_line_items.order_id
WHERE orders.start>='SOME DATETIME' AND orders.end<='SOME DATETIME'
GROUP BY product_options.id
```

Also, just a comment, `product_options` should probably just be named `products`. Shorter table names for the win!

Comment: I just thought more about good table names. I would go with `order`, `item`, and `order_item`.